# How can I stop the onPostExecute() method from executing if I already stored all string from the loop to a vector class?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-json

On the `Magazine.java`, I implemented the `onPostExecute()` method of the asynctask, I have read some tutorial that `onPostExecute()` method of the asynctask will going to continue even though I already got the result from the `doInBackground()` method, in my case, I have a loop in my `onPostExecute()` method wherein I want to get each of the JSONObject of a JSONArray coming from the result of `doInBackGround()` method,convert it to string, and store each of the `JSONObject` to a vector:

```
@Override
public void onPostExecute(String result) {

    try{
    JSONObject jsonRootObj = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObj.optJSONArray("Data");
    int pagenumber = jsonArray.length();

    for (int x = 0; x<=pagenumber; x++){
        String jsonObjStr = jsonArray.getJSONObject(x).toString();
        jsonObjStr = "{ \n \"Data\": \n " + jsonObjStr + " \n }";
        objs.addElement(jsonObjStr);
    }       
    mag_samp.setText(objs.elementAt(0));
    //just to check if the vector objs has a content, I called the very first element but it doenst return anything
    } catch(JSONException e){

    }
}
```

`mag_samp` textview does not displaying anything, what is the best way to fix this? Is the continuous execution of `onPostExecute()` method has a effect on the logical error?

Comment: `onPostExecute()` is called only after the `doInBackground()` is finshed. I think you are confusing `onPostExecute()` with `onProgressUpdate()`..see  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @John Ranniel Sinel you are using  `for (int x = 0; x<=pagenumber; x++)`  here you use `x<=`  
change it to `x<pagenumber`
It is going in catch block

Comment: Please see your log cat and check weather it shows any JSONEXCEPTION OR NOT

Comment: It's already okay, thanks for the help, I think I just got some problem with the loop structure :)

Comment: OnpPostExecute will be called only once that is after the doInBackground completes is execution. Raf the doc again and I'm sure you'll be able to distribute the code perfectly among the callbacks. .